# Fastest (loads and saves) way to store large 2D array

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I've got a 2,000 x 2,000 2D array of objects:

```
 public class Plants
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }

}
```

I'm asking for suggestions on what would be the fastest (for writing and reading) the entire file in one gulp? That is to say, I'm never going to need to seek into this file and read/write from a specific location.

Any thoughts?

---

Thanks for the feedback!
I ended up using binarywriter. The size of the file is ~ 55MB and it saves/loads pretty fast (~ couple of secs).

Comment: You can't use a database? What type of file do you need?

Comment: I can't answer this until you post the code for the `Zombies` class.

Comment: That class produces an object, which is one of your "D"'s.  Where's the other?

Comment: Have you already tried something, like serilation and file write/read?

Comment: @DonBoitnott got it right. We need to know what the other dimension is before we can help you.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `BinaryWriter` to write it, and `BinaryReader` to read it back. If you do that, you can get a little performance increase by specifying a larger buffer (suggest 64K) when you open your streams.

Comment: Curious why commenters think there needs to be another object. You can have a 2D array of `int`, right? Why not a 2D array of `Plant`?

Comment: I second Jim's suggestion of BinaryWriter.

Comment: I must admit, I was thinking BinaryWriter, too.

Comment: Another option would be Binary Serialization, although I don't know if you can serialize a 2D array directly. If you can, the code would be very small. The output would be slightly larger than if you used `BinaryWriter`, but the load/save times probably wouldn't differ by more than a couple of seconds. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's really difficult to answer "fastest" questions like this.  The problem is that each of your hard drive, cpu, memory size, memory speed, motherboard, etc. are potentially different from mine.  Then, file size and data shape matters as well.

Loading an uncompressed file can work better for large files on systems with very fast disks and average or slow CPUs.  Decompressing a file might work better on systems with fast CPUs and average to slow disk drives.  Now, throw memory usage and access speed into the mix.

Once you handle the potential impact of all of that, you need to also deal with the circumstances surrounding use of the data within the software. Can you load it once and use it repeatedly?  Then you don't need to care about the speed of loading quite as much as you might have thought.  Or do you need to read and write it very frequently, with only small changes here and there?  Then you should consider random-access storage or using a database instead.

Now that you've looked at all of those concerns (and there are many more), you might be thinking, "Is it worth all of that effort?"  If you are thinking that way, then you're at the right spot.

Don't pre-optimize.  Pick something that will work *well* (not necessarily the absolute best), then optimize later if it needs help.

Comment: Very good advice. Yes, this is a read it once and never bother with it again.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest is you hand reading/writing bytes to a stream and having a length for Name written as well so it can be deserialized.

Almost as fast (and much easier) would be Protobuf-Net (binary protocol with easy to define interface) or Json.Net + Zip.  Protobuf can be tweaked to write a length header in case you need to stream out Plants as they're processed.

GZipStream or DeflateStream should also be looked at because it may offer a benefit when accessing that much data from the disk in one shot.